# Uploading a file using Selenium

Tags: php, testing, automation, automated-tests, selenium-rc

How do I upload a file using Selenium tool in automation testing? I tried with the following code:

```
selenium.attachFile(//*[@id='file-uploader']/div/div[1]",
    "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Malformed URL C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.png.
```

Comment: Did you try with "file:///C:/Users/Public...."

Comment: No.. can you please share me the entire url?

Comment: Try "file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Desert.jpg"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and let you know.

Comment: It dint work for me.. Am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be in this format:

```
file://C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample%20Pictures\Desert.jpg
```

We're dealing with the Windows world, so the slashes are backwards.

Try this:

```
selenium.attachFile(//*[@id='file-uploader']/div/div[1]",
"file://C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg");
```

Comment: I don't know if you have to escape the space or not. Try it both ways and tell me which way works. I'll update my answer.